# Problems in setting styles via setStyleSheet() in Qt?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I tried to do is to encapsulate a customized combobox using `setStyleSheet()`.How can I apply all styles described here [customizing-qcombobox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox) to my **QComboBox** object? I encoutered prblems when I tried to achieve my goal.

I know I can use the following to append styles when necessary:`ui.comboxFps->setStyleSheet(ui.comboxFps->styleSheet().append(QString("some styles you need to set")));`

I encountered a problem, that is described as follows.Things like `ui.comboxFps->setStyleSheet(ui.comboxFps->styleSheet().append(QString("color:red;")));`
functioned well as expected.

But:`ui.comboxFps->setStyleSheet(ui.comboxFps->styleSheet().append(QString("QComboBox{color:red;} QComboBox::down-arrow:on { left: 1px;}")));` which has **QComboBox{** didn't function.

I tried it in another way.

`QFile styleFile( ":Resources/comboxStyle.qss" );
 styleFile.open( QFile::ReadOnly );
 QString style( styleFile.readAll() );
 ui.comboxFps->setStyleSheet( style );`

In **comboxStyle.qss** are something like [customizing-qcombobox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox). It didn't work either.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you want to append stylesheets to already existing stylesheet? By the way, there is no `QColor` property for `QComboBox`. I don't know if that's a typo in the question, or if it's in your actual code.

Comment: @thuga the **Qcolor** here is a typo in my question,the codes here are snippets for expressing.Sorry,appending is not key here.What I exactly want to do is that set **QComboBox**'s drop-down and down-arrow style as described here [customizing-qcombobox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox).

Comment: @thuga Actually When I just **setStyleSheet** like 'ui.comboxFps->setStyleSheet((QString("QComboBox::down-arrow:on{Qcolor:red;} QComboBox::down-arrow {image: url(……);}")));',it didn't work either.All I want to know is how to apply styles described here [customizing-qcombobox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox) to my **QComboBox** object.

Comment: Does this work: `ui.comboxFps->setStyleSheet("QComboBox{color: red; background-color: blue;}");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem I encountered. (Assumed that *btnTest* is a `QPushButton` object)

When you set style via Qt-Designer's `styleSheet` property, QWidget's `styleSheet()` returns a QString like

```
color: gray;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-radius:3px;
```

without prefix and suffix like

```
QPushButton{……}`.Then `btnTest->setStyleSheet(btnTest->styleSheet().append(QString(QPushButton{border:url(……correct image path);})))
```

it doesn't function well, the correct thing is

```
btnTest->setStyleSheet( QString("{") + btnTest->styleSheet()+ QString("}") + QString("QPushButton{border:url(……correct image path);}") )
```

Please pay attention to `QString("{")` and `QString("}")`.